# Is it possible to put events onto an EventBridge event bus from a partner integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to send an event to an event bus created by a third party integration with AWS, specifically Shopify.

The ARN for that resource looks more or less like: `arn:aws:events:us-east-1:****:event-bus/aws.partner/shopify.com/****/some-shopify-events`

When I try to use *either* v2 or v3 of the AWS sdk for Javascript to send an event, I get a validation error:

> ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:events:us-east-1:----:event-bus/aws.partner/shopify.com/----/shopify-events-dev' at 'entries.1.member.eventBusName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (arn:aws[\w-]*:events:[a-z]{2}-[a-z]+-[\w-]+:[0-9]{12}:event-bus/)?[.-_A-Za-z0-9]+

The problem seems to be that the regex is does not match `/`s in the bus name, i.e the part after `event-bus/`.

Is this a bug or is this intentional? I thought it might be a bug only in v3, but when I go the same result in v2, I started to wonder if it is intentional?

Is there no way to send an event to an event bus with a name like that created by this partner integration?

Comment: Why are you trying to put events there? The API for those event buses seems to be https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutPartnerEvents.html - which you are not allowed to call.

Comment: That's interesting. I hope that we can write to the partner event bus because we want to write an e2e test that starts by triggering an event. Maybe an alternative would be to deploy some temporary infrastructure (maybe a rule on another event bus) just for the test. 

Comment: Asked a question on the aws repository (v3) about this. Looks like somebody took a look at it, but no actual answer yet: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is a categorical no.

See this response from one of the maintainers of the AWS-SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3714#issuecomment-1407260809

Comment: could you elaborate on this with other facts and references to back up this claim?